# Kendo UI grid filter doesn't work when opening a popup before

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, popup, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid where some of the columns can be filtered. For each row in that column, you can open a popup to see some details to the specific entry.

I can open the popup without any problems. But: after closing it and trying to filter any of the columns, I get the following error: *JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'toggle' of undefined or null reference*

If I filter a column before I open a popup, it works like a charm. 
If I filter a column and then open the popup, the already filtered column can be filtered again but the others not.

I don't know why I can't filter columns after opening and closing the popup.

Any ideas or hints would be really helpful. Thanks

HTML:

```
<div id="windoofTestOuter"><div id="windoofTest"></div></div>      
<div id="processGrid"></div>
```

My grid:

```
    $("#processGrid").kendoGrid({
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        selectable: true,
        filterable: {
            extra: false
        },
        dataSource: {
            type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Home/GetProcesses",
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function (data) {
                    return $.extend({}, data, { sort: data.sort, filter: data.filter });
                }
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            page: "@ViewBag.ProcessPage",
            schema: { data: "Data", total: "Total", model: { id: "Id" } },
            pageSize: "@(@Model.MaxCountToShow)"
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "ErrorDateTime", title: "ProcessDateTime", width: "170px"/*, filterable: { ui: dateFilter }*/ },
            { field: "Name", title: "Processtype", attributes: { value: "type" }, width: "240px;", filterable: { ui: processtypeFilter} },
            { field: "Service", title: "Service", width: "181px;", filterable: { ui: serviceFilter } },
            { field: "Operation", title: "Operation", width: "130px", filterable: { ui: operationFilter } }
        ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

The link/string which shall open the popup:

```
 function createProcessActionString(process) {
            var det = '<a class="makeANiceMouse" onclick="processDetailUrl(' + process.Id + ', ' + grid.dataSource.page() + ')">Details</a>';                
            return det;                
 }
```

My popup:

```
function processDetailUrl(id, page) {
    var windoof = $("#windoofTest").kendoWindow({
              width: "1150px",
              height: "300px",
              content: det,
              title: "Process Details",
              actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize", "Close"],
              close: function (e) {
                     windoof.data("kendoWindow").content(" ");
              }
    });

    windoof.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
}
```

I deleted the unnecessary columns and so on..

**EDIT**: I tried to intitialize the filter in the *filterMenuInit*. After opening and closing the popup, I clicked on the filter icon of one of the columns, and I get the error : *JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'toggle' of undefined or null reference* . The same one as before.

**EDIT**: I used the *windoof.destroy()* but the filters weren't accessable afterwards.

**EDIT** *solution*: I have a workaround for working with the filters again. I just fake a click on each of it before I open a popup. It's not beautiful but it serves me so far.

**BUT** It seems like everything gets kicked/killed by that damn popup. I can't even access the grid's datasource anymore.. It's strange...

Comment: I think you have some problem with filterMenuInit event: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filterMenuInit Can you share your gird and popup code?

Comment: I've tried my best to reproduce it but in the newest kendo (2014.3.1119) I do not see error like this. Mby you should upgrade your kendo? Or if you can reproduce it on fiddle it would be wonderfull :) I guess kendo can not open filer animation container because it supposes that your window is still open. So mby try add `windoof.destroy();` at your window close event last line. You're creating the new one window object after click in processDetailUrl anyway.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it on jsfiddle but I cant open that damn popup.. I had the same idea with the popup not really closing by clicking close. I tried *windoof.destroy();* but after it was destroyed, I got the error: *Unable to get property 'open' of undefined*... I read somewhere that the popup gets destroyed automatically by clicking close.. Furthermore, I can still use the paginating and detailgrid...

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same issues but got well passed the Data not being there. Check out   or use onDataBound and use e.sender to get a handle to the Grid Object opposed to .data("KendoGrid") from the onClose of the popup this is what fixed it for me. I'm still trying to get my filters to work though after the pop up closes.